# c++ class the output doesn't display completely

Tags: c++

This code produces no errors, but in the output just this line will show up then the program exits:

```
cout << "write 1 for areaoftrapezium and 2 for areaofrhombus and 3 for                      areaofParallelogram " << endl;
cin >> option;
```

and here the full code I don't know what is wrong

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

 class project
{

private:
float base, base2, height;
float diagonal, diagonal2;
float base3, aldtude;
  public:
void trapezium() {

    float areaoftrapezium;
    areaoftrapezium = 0.5*(base + base2)*height;
    cout << "the area of trapezium is:" << areaoftrapezium;
  }
void rhombus() {

    float areaofrhombus;
    areaofrhombus = 0.5*diagonal*diagonal2;
    cout << "the  area of rhombus is:" << areaofrhombus;
}
void Parallelogram() {

    float areaofParallelogram;
    areaofParallelogram = base3*aldtude;
    cout << "the  area of Parallelogram is:" << areaofParallelogram;
}

project(int a, int b, int c){
    base = a;
    base2 = b;
    height = c;
}
project(int d, int e) {

    diagonal = d;
    diagonal2 = e;

}


float getbase() {
    return base;
}
float getbase2() {
    return base2;
}
float getheight() {
    return height;
}
float getdiagonal() {
    return diagonal;

}
float getdiagonal2() {
    return diagonal2;
}
float getbase3() {
    return base3;
}
float getaldtude() {
    return aldtude;
}
};

int main()

   {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, h;

int option = 0;

project obj();


cout << "write 1 for areaoftrapezium and 2 for areaofrhombus and 3 for areaofParallelogram " << endl;
cin >> option;
switch (option) {

case  '1':
{
    cout << "Enter the value for two bases & height of the trapezium: " <<     endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

     project obj(a, b, c);
     obj.trapezium();

}
break;

case  '2':
{
    cout << "Enter diagonals of the given rhombus:" << endl;
    cin >> d;
    cin >> e;
    project obj( d,  e);
    obj.rhombus();
}
break;

case  '3':
{
    cout << "Enter base and altitude of the given Parallelogram:  " << endl;
    cin >> f;
    cin >> h;
    project obj( f,  h);

    obj.Parallelogram();

}
break;

}

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding a default block in your switch-case and see if it goes in it.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing numbers, like one, with digits, like `'1'`. They are completely different things. The number one is how many heads I have. The digit "1" is a mark that can represent the number one in the Arabic numeral system.

```
int option = 0;
```

Okay, `option` is an integer.

```
cin >> option;
```

And you read an integer from the user.

```
switch (option) {
case  '1':
```

And then you compare it to the character `1`, except you wanted to compare it to the number one.

If you read numbers from the user, compare them to numbers like one. If you read characters from the user, compare them to characters like `'1'`. Keep it straight.